# jQuery and save the paremeters between pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, spring

Is it possible to remember the height of the div? For example, on a single website, I expand the div that has some content and I click on another page with different content but with the same div (same id and class). Unfortunately, everything refreshes and loses height of the div.

I got the effect as the frames in html (but how u see it doesn't work as I would like to). How's it take? Keep the data in the session? Need example...

I am using jQuery, Spring MVC if someone asks

Comment: Take a look at [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage ♦ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use HTML5 localStorage mechanism.

You can use `.height()`, `.innerHeight()` or `outerHeight()` based on what you need.

[image]

> Here's the example - [jsfiddle.net/xK0nB1n](http://jsfiddle.net/xK0nB1n/jfmaLhk3/1/)

**jquery**

```
if(localStorage.divheight) //extract the old height
{ 
    // handle the height as you want here
    alert('Old height from local storage: '+ localStorage.divheight);
}

//Code just to show the mechanism of LocalStorage
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#result').click (function () {

        //Remember the height
      localStorage.divheight = $("div").height(); 

       //Tell the user the freshly stored height
      alert("New height: "+localStorage.divheight);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="result">
    Some number of lines here....
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
    . Fuga earum id fugit veritatis! Pariatur, magni.
</div>
```